# Why realloc fails with temporary pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, realloc

The following works successfully:

```
char *op, op_temp;
op = malloc(len+1);
op_temp = op;
op = realloc(op, ++len);
```

while the following results in a runtime error:

```
char *op, op_temp;
op = malloc(len+1);
op_temp = op;
op = realloc(op_temp, ++len);
```

Why so even though the same piece of memory is reallocated?

Comment: `char* op, op_temp` and `char *op, op_temp` are the same. That's why I don't put `*` next to the type name (easier to expect that both `op` and `op_temp` will be pointers).

Comment: @woytaz Yes, you're right. Sorry for the mistake. In my head, I wanted to say that `char *op, op_temp` is clear because the asterisk is attached to the variable while `char* op, op_temp` is ambiguous because it looks like `char *` will apply to both variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

op_temp is not a pointer, just a char value. You should write:

```
char *op, *op_temp;
```

or

```
char* op;
char* op_temp;
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) of `realloc()`

> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

so, the first argument should be a `char *`.

OTOH, in your code,

```
op = realloc(op, ++len);
```

Here `op` is of type `char *`, which is valid. But

```
op = realloc(op_temp, ++len);
```

here `op_temp` is of type `char`.

Change

```
char *op, op_temp;
```

to

```
char *op  = NULL, *op_temp = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `op_temp` is not a pointer. You have to put the asterisk `*` next to each variable name that you want to be a pointer. Like this:

```
char *op, *op_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `typedef's` to eliminate such errors as they encode correct pointer types as explained below:

```
typedef char *charp;
charp op, op_temp;
```

NOw the above `op` & `op_temp` declared as pointers o type `char`.